# getting error when trying to enable approle

Tags: containers, hashicorp-vault

I followed this tutorial:

https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-install-hashicorp-vault-on-linux/

$ vault auth enable approle
Error enabling approle auth: Error making API request.

```
URL: POST http://localhost:8200/v1/sys/auth/approle
Code: 400. Errors:

* missing client token
```

my vault is running in a container and I have exposed it by 8200 port do I need to mount volumes ?

Comment: Looks like you need to authenticate. Try `vault login` with an enabled auth method.

Comment: I logged into vault UI with the client token of root and then tried still got the same error

Comment: The vault UI doesn't give the command line its credentials, you need to login using the `vault` command in the same session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `VAULT_TOKEN` env while interacting with the vault server via vault CLI:

```
$ export VAULT_TOKEN="....."
```

Answer (score 1):

That guide is missing the authentication step.

You will need to to provide a header in your curl request, for example

```
curl --header 'X-Vault-Token: s.5iSwFPh0XQa96MSrBHquCFlH' https://vault.blah/v1/...
```